# Display value in view using key from Angular key-value array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<li class="dropup">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
           {{selectedHub}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable">
                        <li ng-repeat="hub in hubs">
                           <a ng-click="selectHub(hub.Key)" href="">{{hub.Value}}</a>
                         </li> 
                </ul>                   
        </li>
```

I have a dropdown list of ID's and I have angular "key value array" that stores ID and Value information.I want to display the value against selected ID. I have written some code for reference how I am trying to achieve this.

```js
$scope.hubs = [];  $scope.selectedHub = null;
$scope.selectHub = function (data) {
        $scope.selectedHub = data;
    };
```

It would be much appreciated, if anyone can help me. Also, please let me know if question is not clear, I will try to improve. This is my first question. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to display the dropdown or the result of the selected dropdown ?

Comment: I have angular "key value array" ??? , can you show this object??

Comment: @Weedoze I am trying to display result of selected dropdown.

Comment: @Simarpreetkaur Where is the code of the dropdown ? What is the array populating the dropdown ?

Comment: <ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable">
                        <li ng-repeat="hub in hubs">
                           <a ng-click="selectHub(hub.Key)" href=""{{hub.Value }}</a>
                         </li> 
     </ul>

Comment: @Simarpreetkaur Please edit your question. What is `hubs` ? What is `selectHub()` ?

Comment: @Weedoze hub in controller is  $scope.hubs = [];

Comment: @weedoze  $scope.selectHub = function (data) {
        $scope.selectedHub = data;
    };

Comment: and I have another variable in controller $scope.selectedHub that stores ID of selected hub.

Comment: @Simarpreetkaur Please update your question. Don't post code in the comments section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps , can you please check once , I have passed hub to function and displaying  Key and Value , if you want to display only Value you can  useselectedHub.Value

```js
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myCrtl",function($scope){
$scope.hubs = [{Key:1,Value:"val1"},{Key:2,Value:"val2"},{Key:3,Value:"val3"}];  $scope.selectedHub = null;
$scope.selectHub = function (data) {
        $scope.selectedHub = data;
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCrtl">
<li class="dropup">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
           {{selectedHub.Key}}--{{selectedHub.Value}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable">
                        <li ng-repeat="hub in hubs">
                           <a ng-click="selectHub(hub)" href="">{{hub.Value}}</a>
                         </li> 
                </ul>                   
        </li>
        
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Srinivas!! This is exactly what I wanted to do :)

Comment: Can you please accept this answer if it meets your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display id and select object you can use ng-options , Consider your values object as below

```
$scope.values = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'abc1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    value: 'abc2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    value: 'abc3'
  }];
```

you can use ng-options as

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="value.id for value in values"/>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCrtl", function($scope) {

  $scope.values = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'abc1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    value: 'abc2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    value: 'abc3'
  }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCrtl">

This is selected Value : {{selectedValue}}<br><br>
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="value.id for value in values"/>



</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas This works with select list , but I have designed my UI with bootstrap menu that uses <ul> and <li>

Comment: you can pass hub object in selectHub(hub) and assign to $scope variable

Comment: This is what I am trying to do. Please have a look on updated question, but  I am able to just display ID not the value.